# Centralizar uma imagem no java ee

Tags: java-ee

Boa tarde,estou fazendo um trabalho para a faculdade e queria saber como faço centralizar esta imagem em java web

```
<h:graphicImage url="../resources/images/logo.jpg"/>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui...

```
<center>
<h:graphicImage url="../resources/images/logo.jpg"/>
</center>
```